# Implementation of Concurrent Queue + map in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, data-structures, concurrency, tbb

I am not very good at data structures, so this might be very silly question. I am looking for a way to implement a hybrid behavior of queue + maps.

I am currently using `tbb::concurrent_bounded_queue` (documented at [Intel's developer zone](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506201)) from [www.threadingbuildingblocks.org](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org) in a multithreaded single producer single consumer process. The queue has market data quote objects and the producer side of the process is actually highly time sensitive, so what I need is a queue that is keyed on a market data identifier such as USDCAD, EURUSD. The Value points (through `unique_ptr`) to most latest market data quote that I received for this key.

So, let us say my queue has 5 elements for 5 unique identifiers and suddenly we get updated market data quote for the identifier at 3rd position in the queue, then I just store the most latest value and discard the value I previously had. So, essentially I just move my unique_ptr to the new market data quote for this key.

It's like it is similar to `concurrent_bounded_queue<pair<string, unique_ptr<Quote>>>` but is keyed on the first element of the pair.

I am not sure if this is already available in a third-party library (may be tbb itself) or what it is called if it is a standard data structure.

I would highly appreciate any help or guidance on this.

Thanks.

Comment: an illustration of the data structure would be helpful to understand the task

Answer (score 0):

First, observe that we can easily write...

```
int idn_to_index(idn); // map from identifier to contiguous number sequence
```

...it doesn't matter much if that uses a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`, binary search in a sorted `std::vector`, your own character-by-character hardcoded parser....

Then the producer could:

1. update (using a mutex) a `std::vector<unique_ptr<Quote>>` at `[idn_to_index(idn)]`
2. post the index to `concurrent_bounded_queue<int>`

The consumer:

1. pop an index
2. compares the pointer in `std::vector<unique_ptr<Quote>>` at [index] to its own array of last-seen pointers, and if they differ process the quote

The idea here is not to avoid having duplicate identifier-specific indices in the queue, but to make sure that the stalest of those still triggers processing of the newest quote, and that less-stale queue entries are ignored harmlessly until the data's genuinely been updated again.

Answer (score 0):

TBB provides

- `concurrent_undordered_map`: no concurrent erase, stable iterators, no element access protection;
- `concurrent_hash_map`: has concurrent erase, concurrent operations invalidate iterators, per-element access management via 'accessors'

So, if the question
"`It's like it is similar to concurrent_bounded_queue<pair<string, unique_ptr<Quote>>> but is keyed on the first element of the pair`" means suggest a corresponding concurrent associative map container, these two are at your service. Basically, you have to choose between the ability to erase identifiers concurrently (hash_map) and the ability to traverse concurrently across all the elements (unordered_map). `concurrent_hash_map` also simplifies synchronization of accesses to the elements which looks useful for your case.

Comment: Yeah. I was looking at `concurrent_hash_map` and was trying to figure out how I can communicate between the `"new message received"` callback and a corresponding `insert` into the `concurrent_hash_map`. The consumer side would basically get the latest `Quote` from the `hash_map` and erase it. Hence, if the speed of `insert`s is faster than the speed of `erase`s I will still have the latest quote available for processing. But, this still doesn't have a queue-like behavior..right? The hard part is to integrate this `hash_map` with the incoming queue of `Quote`s. What do you think?

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what do you want to achieve, doesn't Tony answer you question (just replacing vector with hash_map..)?
From what I understood I guess, you don't need to erase quotes, just update them if the time-stamp is newer than the one which was stored

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem as below:

I use a `queue` and a `hashmap` both from `tbb` library. Now, I push my unique identifiers on the `queue` and not the `Quote`'s. My `hashmap` has my unique identifier as key and Quote as value

So, when I receive a `Quote` I iterate through the `queue` and check whether the `queue` contains that identifier, if it does, then I insert the corresponding `Quote` directly into the `hashmap` and do not add the unique identifier on the `queue`. If it does not, then I push the identifier on the `queue` and corresponding `Quote` in hashmap. This, ensures that my `queue` always as unique set of identifiers and my `hashmap` has the most latest `Quote` available for that identifier.

On the consumer side, I pop the `queue` to get my next identifier and get the Quote for that identifier from the `hashmap`.

This works pretty fast. Please let me know in case I am missing any hidden issues with this.

Comment: iterating through concurrent_queue in not thread-safe. if it is not an issue somehow, why to use concurrent_queue and not std::queue?